# How to call controller action with parameters from XSLT href link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, xslt

Hi I am trying to make a call to controller action but I can't see a link in PDF file.

My code in XSLT is as below:

```
  <a href='@Url.Action("DisplayNotification", "Notification", new {{ NotificationId = @NotificationId, WorkInProgress = @WorkInProgress, Notification_Code = @Notification_Code, VehicleCode = @VehicleCode }} )'>
    Read our <b>privacy policy.</b>
  </a>
```

XSLT is used to generate HTML. I just need a clickable link that used to navigate to the action method is there any way to do this.  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two closing brackets `))` at the end?

Comment: You have extra parenthesis `)` on the end of `Url.Action` helper, which causing the problem. Try to remove it and see if the link rendered properly.

Comment: Hi Thanks I have removed but still getting the error "Expected token '}', found ','."

Comment: As you say it is XSLT code I suppose you don't want the curly braces in the attribute value to denote XSLT attribute templates, therefore you need to double them with e.g. `new {{ NotificationId = @NotificationId, WorkInProgress = @WorkInProgress, Notification_Code = @Notification_Code, VehicleCode = @VehicleCode }}`.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen Many thanks I have changed the code, now there is no error but now I am not able to see the hyper link(see only simple text) in PDF file. I have update the question now what is wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve, in what way exactly you try to mix XSLT with MVC and where PDF is used. The code snippet you say is XSLT seems to create an HTML hyperlink, I am not sure how you create PDF from that.

Comment: Hi we have XSLT that is generating HTML but then after we are converting PDF from that.

Comment: Does the HTML at least have a working hyperlink? How do you convert the HTML to PDF?

Comment: @MartinHonnen No hyperlink is not working in HTML, we are converting HTML to PDF by itextsharp - Please help me on how to call controller method from XSLt.